# ImageMagick: Exact remap of greyscale values to RGB ones

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick 6.8 and I have LUT color table created in text format:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 848,1,255,srgb
0,0:   (0  , 0  , 0  )    #000000
1,0:   (226, 226, 224)    #E2E2E0
2,0:   (48 , 74 , 0  )    #304A00
# ... 
# few hundred more colors
```

Which has one colour per grayscale value (between 0 and 848 in my use case).

So, I want to convert a grayscale image to RGB one, using this LUT without any fancy gamma corrections, colour space remaps, interpolations and etc. Just straight replacement. How to do it?

Current issues start since the beginning:

Trying to `convert lut.txt lut.png` with various options always give me more colours than they are actually. In the LUT, there are 540 unique colours, but inspecting the generated PNG, or even `identify lut.txt` reports 615! This means that the LUT is not interpreted straight at all.

On the other hand, even if I succeed to read the LUT exactly, or probably avoid converting it to PNG, there comes another problem. Using `-clut` maps the whole greyscale range (0-65535) to the LUT, so I guess I have to normalize it first. But this screws up the greyscales input to begin with.

P.S. An answer which might be useful here is, if there is image format with bigger than 8-bit indexed palette. Then that text LUT be used as its palette  and the greyscale raster as its pixel values.

Answer (score 3):

In Imagemagick, use -clut to process a grayscale image with a colored look-up table image to colorize the grayscale image.

First create a 3-color color table LUT image with red, green and blue hex colors. I show an enlarged version.

```
convert xc:"#ff0000" xc:"#00ff00" xc:"#0000ff" +append colortable.gif
```

[image]

Here is the input - a simple gradient that I will colorize.

[image]

Now apply the color table image to the gradient using -clut.

```
convert gradient.png colortable.gif -clut gradient_colored.png
```

[image]

The default is a linear interpolation. But if you only want to see the 3 colors, then use `-interpolate nearest-neighbor`.

```
convert gradient.png colortable.gif -interpolate nearest-neighbor -clut gradient_colored2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for this beautiful answer! I have two questions/remarks though:
1) How easy it is to create a a colortable.gif, in your example, of 800 and more colors?
2) In the example with the gradient, I search for the effect that, only 3 pixel rows would be coloured. This means, the rest would have some default value. In practice there is no need of default value, but as the greyscale gradient has like 256 values, this means I need 256 colour table. And in my application I need more than 800 or more colours (see my 1st question).

Comment: You listed only 3 colors, so I assumed you only had need of a few. Otherwise, I think it depends upon how your 800 colors are organized. Can a script create them from some equation? If not, then you can script to read them from a plain text file or create the text file in the txt format and Imagemagick will read that directly into an image. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#txt.

Comment: Thanks fmw42. I updated a bit the problem so to be more clear. I have the full text LUT, but there are issues with ImageMagick interpreting it. And later using it, as my grayscales does not extent to the full 16-bit range.

Comment: Try `convert \( your_image -auto-level \) LUT.txt -interpolate nearest-neighbor -clut result_image` That will expand your image data to fill the full 16-bit range. Then the color range in your LUT.txt will match to the image. Not sure if it will match the exact colors to the gray levels in the image you want, though.

Comment: That's my worry too. It is just not so pixel precise as I want. If you have say 300 values, they do not fit well into 65535. So, at the end I wrote a custom tool for that purpose, but feels ackward and I will appreciate a solution with generic tool. Thanks again for your help and effort.